# Class with property that can be one of two different types

Tags: c#, class, telegram-bot

I'm developing a Telegram bot in C# but have difficulty with implementing `Message` type. According to [API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), `chat` field can be either of type `User` or of type `GroupChat`. How do I implement that in C#?

So far I could only come up with following code using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
public class Update {
....
  [JsonProperty("chat")]
  public User chat { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("chat")]
  public GroupChat group_chat { get; set; }
....
}
```

But it doesn't work with my WebAPI 2 controller method since I deserialize `Message` using `FromBody` attribute:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string token, [FromBody] Update update)
```

(type `Update` has a field `message` of type `Message`)

Is there any better way to implement `Message` type?

Comment: A better way to say it would be that a class property could be one of two different types.

Comment: @crashmstr right, I renamed the question

Answer (score 3):

Since you are supposed to handle seemingly two completely different objects in one field I don't think you can use strongly-typed objects but you can use a dynamic type for the chat field such as

```
public class Telegram
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public dynamic chat { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access the variables and check if they are null or not to understand if it's a user or a group chat:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"{ ""chat"": { ""id"": 1, ""first_name"": ""my_first_name"", ""last_name"": ""my_last_name"",  ""username"": ""my_username"" }, ""message_id"": 123 }";
    var telegram = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Telegram>(json);
    string name = telegram.chat.first_name; // name = my_first_name
    string title = telegram.chat.title; // title = null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build your `Message` type as an interface (`IMessage`), and then implement it with `GroupMessage` and `UserMessage` classes.

```
interface IMessage
{
   int id;

   //...

   object chat {get;}
}

public class GroupMessage : IMessage
{
   public int id;
   public GroupChat group;
   public object chat {get {return group;} }
}

public class UserMessage : IMessage
{
   public int id;
   public User user;
   public object chat {get {return user;} }
}
```

But what I would really do is handle this at a higher level. Looking at the docs here, rather than a complex object that can handle all of this I would think in terms of **sending** or **receiving** a message. Then I would think of all of the **actions** you might want to do when receiving a message. From there I would have an object that can raise an **event** for each of those actions. When you receive *data* (don't think of it as a message), you parse the data and perhaps raise several events from what was one Telegram message object. Some of those events may require class definitions for the data needed by the event, but now we're talking something that's much narrower in scope; a better fit for the Single Responsibility Principle.

Going the other direction (sending data rather than receiving), the object would have methods for the different kinds of things you might do when sending data. Some of those methods may require classes for the data needed. When possible, use the same classes you did for the receiving events. It might even be just one `Send()` method with many overloads.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in Java as well. As both C# and Java are strong typed languages, my issue was similar. 
I solved this by creating a generic `Chat` class. This `Chat` class contains the properties from `User` as well as from `GroupChat`. The class also has the methods `isUser()`, `isGroupChat()`, `asUser()` and `asGroupChat()`.

I have to admit I have no knowledge of C#, so I can not write an example in that language for you, but here is the body of the `Chat` class, in Java:

```
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("first_name")
private String firstName;

@SerializedName("last_name")
private String lastName;

@SerializedName("username")
private String username;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

public boolean isUser() {
    return title == null;
}

public boolean isGroupChat() {
    return !isUser();
}

public User asUser() {
    return new User(id, firstName, username, lastName);
}

public GroupChat asGroupChat() {
    return new GroupChat(id, title);
}
```

It's quite verbose and adds duplicate code, so if anyone has any additions, I'd like to hear them as well.