# Can two classes with matching property names of type "int" and "long" be united under one interface?

Tags: c#

I have a project with many different auto-generated classes who share many of the same properties. But one of their "shared" properties is declared as an int in some, and a long in others:

```
public class Book {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Movie {
    long Id { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to unite these two classes under a common interface:

```
public interface Media {
    int/long Id;
}
```

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874558/can-int-and-long-be-the-same-type) that I can't treat them as the same type, because they aren't.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828980/class-with-property-that-can-be-one-of-two-different-types) I thought I might declare the field as `dynamic` in the interface. But this gives me errors because the implementing classes declare the field as `int` or `long`, not as `dynamic`.

The classes are auto-generated from database tables which I do not have the ability to change, so I cannot make the classes all use long or all use int.

Is there an elegant, C-sharpy way to represent both an int and a long in one interface?

Comment: Write an interface that has one or the other, and [implement it explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) in both classes. `dynamic` for this purpose would be madness.

Comment: Are you sure you can't hook into the auto-generation process somehow?

Comment: Building on @Blorgbeard answer - if you can annotate which database columns these properties map to, you could have "int _id" which maps to database column "Id", and another property "long Id => (long)_id". But - again - this relies on you being able to change how the files are "auto-generated"

Comment: Forgive the error in type casting in the comment above.. You'd need to use Convert.ToInt64(_id) instead of (long)_id.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *way to represent both an int and a long in one interface*.

It is like wanted having a car being at the same time a Smart and a Toyota.

I don't know if it will solve your problem but you can create a generic interface:

```
public interface IMedia<T>
where T : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
  T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Book : IMedia<int>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Movie : IMedia<long>
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Because there is no true generic polymorphism in C#, it may can't help you... and even with, `int` (4 bytes) and `long` (8 bytes) are two different types.

[About the lack of true generic polymorphism and the missing diamond operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948/how-to-create-list-of-open-generic-type-of-classt/58571001#58571001)

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class ObjectWithId
{
  private long _Id;
  public int IdAsInt
  {
    get { return checked((int)_Id); }
    set { _Id = (long)value; }
  }
  public long IdAsLong
  {
    get { return _Id; }
    set { _Id = value; }
  }
}

public class Book : ObjectWithId
{
}

public class Movie : ObjectWithId
{
}
```

You can create an interface if you need:

```
public interface IObjectWithId
{
  public int IdAsInt { get; set; }
  public long IdAsLong { get; set; }
}
```

But you say classes are auto-generated... so can you modify them with interface or abstract parent?

And if you can, why not standardize Ids?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous answer, this is my solution to the issue. I have a DB with both int and long primary keys. I would like to access the Id when passing in a generic object T:

```
public interface IBaseModel<T>
    where T : struct
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

My DTO base:

```
public abstract class BaseModel<T> : IBaseModel<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

DTOs with int Ids will then look like this

```
public class IntModel : BaseModel<int>
{
}
```

DTOs with long Ids will then look like this

```
public class LongModel : BaseModel<long>
{
}
```

Most importantly, when I want to use these DTOs as generic parameters in methods or classes:

```
static void DoSomething<T>(IBaseModel<T> printMe)
    where T : struct
{
    Console.WriteLine(printMe.Id);
}
```

Passing these models are now nice and generic:

```
IntModel intModel = new IntModel();
intModel.Id = 1;

LongModel longModel = new LongModel();
longModel.Id = 2;

DoSomething(intModel);
DoSomething(longModel);
```